# Laravel Voyager, update on 1 table, update on another

Tags: php, database, laravel, web-applications, voyager

- Language: PHP
- Framework: Laravel
- Dependency / Library: Laravel Voyager

I have 3 Database tables: **Users**, **Schedule of Reviews** and **Appointments**.

The users can reserve many schedules, and schedules can be reserved by many users, so basically, the **Appointments** table is my associative entity to connect the **Users** and **Schedule of Reviews** tables

In my installed Laravel Voyager, the **Appointments** table has a column **status** to be marked as **Paid / Not yet Paid**

Now, Whenever the Admin changes the **status** to **PAID**, I want the **slots column** from the **Schedule of Appointments** table to be decremented or decreased by 1 to literally mark that the user has successfully paid his/her slot for the schedule of review

May I know how or where can I add such code so when Laravel Voyager updates the **Appointments** table, I can also update the **Schedule of Reviews** table?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to achieve this particular scenario is by overriding model, you can implement logic in your Model, which I am assuming App\ScheduleAppointments:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

    class ScheduleAppointments extends Model 
    {
        //Your model logic
        //
        //
        //
        //

    /**
     * OVERRIDE Boot Method
     */
        protected static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();
            static::updating(function ($appointment) {
            if($appointment->status == 'PAID'){
                 $appointment->slot -=1;
            }    
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: However, for this one, if I'll be updating the details of the Appointment, even not the "status" column, it would make the slots decremented, is there a way for me to specify that the admin has updated the status, then that's the only moment I can decrement the slot?

Comment: Yeahh, , you will have the appointment object in the model, Basically, you can check
if($appointment->status == 'PAID'){ $appointment->slot -=1;}  
In that way you will be  updating only in the case of status changed

Comment: Thank you sir Saad! Laravel Events did the work! thank you very much!